# Outside of cold working method, are there other methods to forge metal that's constantly below zero temperature?

Tags: science-based, metalworking

Inspired by this question [How devastating is a weapon that can internally and rapidly cool down a section of a human body?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/183580/how-devastating-is-a-weapon-that-can-internally-and-rapidly-cool-down-a-section), I wonder what kind of blacksmith method could be used for forging or smithing a sword or other melee weapon with a metal that constantly has ice cold temperature below zero.

- Assuming the metal still has steel hardness or has high quality spring steel/high quality carbon steel properties outside of the melting point due to it constantly in below subzero temperature.
- And outside of cold working method and casting method.
- There's no specific timeline regarding the technology to forge it, so it's fine if the method is a futuristic one as long it's hypothetically/theoretically possible, but would be better if there's a way for traditional method though.

I am not knowledgeable about metallurgy or blacksmithing in general, just wondering if there is any other unique method for forging such a thing, hence I exclude cold working which I think is the common way to deal with this while keeping the quality/hardness of the metal that I know of (assuming it even works for such metal, so correct me if I am mistaken).

Comment: You wanna forge something that you cannot heat up, you'll have to do it in the cold. As for "science-based", there is no such material.

Comment: @Karl i mean science based as a scientific method, as far as i know, tag was mean for the type of answer not to define the question, so even if the question has fiction or fantasy element in it but the OP want a scientific solution, the tag is appropriate. but correct me if i am wrong regarding it though.

Comment: I simply don't understand the question. The metal is cold, and you want to forge it; as a consequence, it will be forged cold. But then you say that you don't want to cold forge it. Isn't this a contradiction? (And what's wrong with *machining* the piece?) (And there cannot possibly be anything which *"has steel properties"* but is always below freezing: for example, an important property of steel is that it becomes hot when machined or worked.)

Comment: @AlexP im not sure am i correct, but i originally though cold forge method was forging in room temperature or just simply hammer or welding it without heating, not literal mean of forging in subzero cold temperature, because as far as i know steel in such sub zero temperature can end up brittle or shatter upon impact hence i ask, and just incase cold forging method is possible in that way because its seems to basic. also iam not against machine forging. regarding the steel properties just think its as simply fiction metal or fantasy metal that has steel properties but constantly ice cold.

Comment: [Forging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forging) and [machining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machining) and very very different processes. Forging works by changing the shape of the piece while preserving its mass; machining works by removing chips from the piece until the desired shape is obtained.

Comment: @AlexP oh...well if it can be use to make sword and the like while maintaining its quality or hardness, i am not against it though. i guess i consider it another method of forging.

Comment: You cannot say that "steel" in general becomes brittle at freezing temperatures; for example, [austenitic stainless steels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austenitic_stainless_steel) remain ductile at cryogenic temperatures. Steel is not *one* material, it is a large family of materials. For example, the [SpaceX Starship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Starship) is made of stainless steel exactly because it has good mechanical properties over a very wide range of temperatures, from the very cold cryogenic propellants to the very hot re-entry.

Comment: @AlexP thats as far i know in general... from other answer, so what steel is use for making sword in medieval europe?  maybe i use that as the properties, otherwise i think i use modern spring steel sword instead, though i dont know the real name for it, is it the one you link?  since iam not knowledgeable at all regarding metallurgy.

Comment: *"What steel is use for making sword in medieval europe?"* The kind of steel that becomes hot when worked. The material described in the question *did not exist in medieval Europe*. It is a different material. Whether this different material becomes brittle when cold, or does not become brittle when cold, whether it can be cold formed or machined in freezing conditions, is *entirely up to you*.

Comment: This depends a lot on the properties of the metal,  "steel" covers a wide range, cold working that is fine for mild steel will shatter  high carbon steel for instance.

Comment: @John do you know what the type or name of high quality medieval steel use for european sword historically? maybe i use that as basis, otherwise i think i try using spring steel as basis .

Comment: Both are high carbon, and will just crack and shatter. generally the stronger the steel the less ductile it is.

Comment: You cannot create a steel sword that will remain at a temperature below freezing. Steel has an excellent thermal conductivity.

Comment: @NomadMaker just think it as fiction/fantasy metal with steel properties

Answer (score 3):

There are many methods of [cold working](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_working) metal. For example, wire and thin sheet metal can easily be bent to shape by human strength. For cold working something as substantial as a sword, human strength won't do the job, and powered machinery is a necessity.

Low-tech powered machinery, such as a water-powered [trip-hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trip_hammer) would still be very slow. For practical work, you need Industrial Revolution technology, such as a [steam hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_hammer).

Without more information on your fantasy metal, it's not possible to say how it will behave under such treatment. It is possible to say something about the tools and dies used to work the metal. These are normally steel, and need to be lubricated for low-temperature work. How rapidly does your fantasy metal dispose of heat? If it will cool the dies to below about -40 centigrade, specialised  [steel alloys](https://www.totalmateria.com/page.aspx?ID=CheckArticle&site=kts&NM=61#:%7E:text=Other%20alloy%20steels%20are%20suitable,Ni%20to%20%2D101%C2%B0C.) will have to be used; ordinary ones will become brittle and break under impact.

Comment: so theres no effect or problem at all if the steel is constantly in sub zero temperature to forge using such method?

Comment: There are many techniques which cold-form steel. How should anyone but you know if they would work with your ever-cold fantasy metal? You can also cnc-mill your sword out of solid block, if it can be milled.

Comment: @LiJun: There are *lots* of possible problems, see edited answer.

Comment: yeah, i was thinking the metal is below -40C temperature base on that other question.

Answer (score 3):

A few of things to consider.

They need electricity so may not be any good for you, but may spur some further ideas.

**Electroplating** let's you add layers of metal to a conductive material.

**Electro-eroding** is basically tiny sparks which rapidly heat up a small area of metal, vaporizing it. The bulk of the metal remains more or less room temperature.

**(Electro)-Etching** Either using electricity or acids you can remove metal. A mask or resist can be applied to control what gets etched. (Electro-etching is kinda the reverse of electroplating fyi)

Answer (score 2):

**Like diamonds**

Diamonds in nature are created by incredible pressures. Artificial diamonds are different from real ones, but mostly in being *superior*. They generally aren't made with pressures seen in nature. One of the most used is with chemical vapor that causes the diamond to "grow". I assume the carbon is settling down in the diamond structure by design. The other is using pressure in combination with high temperatures, which doesn't require the huge pressures present in nature.

A quick search didn't give me anything that suggests the same is possible for iron or many other metals. However, the reason might be that it's just so easy to heat the metals that no research was needed to see if this is possible. It is conceivable that techniques with some chemicals can make the metal form, or with a katalysator to mold the metal. For example, a liquid that binds itself to the metal, making it soft and easily workable. Afterwards the liquid can be drawn from it, leaving the bindings and letting the metal harden again.

Is it really possible? Don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t really know much about this topic, but instead of using a heated tool to mold the material, you could use a rapidly vibrating tool to cut the metal. It would have to be fairly thin to cut, but you could meld sheets. Or lasers! Lasers can be used to cut and cool. I don’t know.